# Python: How do you remove a tag in a tag?

Tags: python

I would like to remove the h4 tag, leaving li intact
I'm using BeautifulSoup

in index.html

```
<li id="myID">
<h4 class="ipsType_minorHeading">Ilość treści</h4>
666
</li>
```

I would like to get

```
  <li id="myID">666</li>
```

my code

```
...
html_file = open("index.html").read()
index_file = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')
```

Comment: Btw, that's not so much of a duplicate since all my searches for the delete and decompose involved answers/questions with `find` rather than `select`, which, at least IMHO, really isn't best practice given Beautifulsoup's support for CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CSS `select` to find the nodes you want, then `decompose` them.  I used the class, since it looked significant, but you could use `h4`, the tag itself, `li h4` (not very normal html, btw) or any CSS that gives the selectivity you need.

```
html = """<li id="myID">
<h4 class="ipsType_minorHeading">Ilość treści</h4>
666
</li>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(html)


for hit in soup.select(".ipsType_minorHeading"):
    hit.decompose()

print(soup.prettify())
```

#### output:

note that html and body tags tend to be added by BeautifulSoup when given a snippet of html.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <li id="myID">
   666
  </li>
 </body>
</html>
```